# Notification used for Azure Notification Hub's DirectSend

Tags: ios, azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I trying to implement DirectSend for ANH .NET SDK.

```
NotificationHubClient.SendDirectNotificationAsync(Notification notification, string deviceHandle);
```

I am wondering what is the best way to work with this **Notification** object? There is no documentation on this anywhere, unlike all of the SendNative calls that exist on the ANH client.

The abstract **Notification** class's constructor

```
public Notification(Dictionary<string, string> additionalHeaders, string tag);
```

What are the *headers* I need to include? At the moment I don't have any

Does it have to include a *tag*? I am not planning on using Installations or Registrations on my hub, so I won't have any tags to work with anyways?

I am assuming I need to make my own concrete types of Notifications and set all the other properties on this object, such as *PlatformType*, *ContentType*, and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification is an abstract class. There are per platform specific notification classes like: AppleNotification/AdmNotification/GCMNotification/WindowsNotification. You should use class corresponding to the platform you are targeting.

The below API helps to pass the additional platform specific headers. And there is no need to pass any tags for direct send.

```
public Notification(Dictionary<string, string> additionalHeaders, string tag);
```

You can find more information about DirectSend here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608572.aspx